# Quote and backslash in sed

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

I have a string that I want to replace by sed, exactly like this:

```
\'string\'
```

With `\` and `'` inclusive. I want to replace by, suppose **quotedstring**, but tried many ways with escaped without success. Examples that didn't work:

- `sed "s:\'string\':quotedstring:g"`
- `sed "s:\\'string\\':quotedstring:g"`
- `sed 's:\\\'string\\\':quotedstring:g'`
- `sed 's:\\'string\\':quotedstring:g'`

Comment: can you show us some real examples of such a text?

Comment: your last attempt can be modified to `sed 's:\\\x27string\\\x27:quotedstring:g'` .. but that requires a sed version that understands hex escapes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed "s/\\\'string\\\'/replace/"
```

---

Problems with your examples:

- `sed 's:foo:bar:g'` you can't use a single quote `'` inside single quotes
- `sed "s:\'string\':replace:g"` if the character after backslash has no special meaning in double quotes `"`, `bash` **will not** remove it. Consequently, `sed` will really receive `\'`. `\'` is a special sequence in `sed`, see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions)
- `sed "s:\\'string\\':replace:g"` this time `bash` will change `\\` to `\`. However, `sed` will once again get `\'`. It will have the same effect as the previous example

=> That is why you need one extra `\`, to escape the special sequence `\'`.

---

- `sed "s:\\\\'string\\\\':replace:g"` this **will work** too! `bash` will change `\\\\` to `\\` and `sed` will receive `\\'`. Special sequence escaped, just like you need
- `sed "s:\\\\\'string\\\\\':replace:g"` ouch, 5 or more backslashes is already too much
- *But I really want to use single quotes*: in that case, you need to break the single quotes wherever you want to insert a literal `'`: `sed 's:\\'\''string\\'\'':replace:g'`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(\\'\''\)string\1/quotedstring/' file
```

`\`'s must be quoted i.e. `\\` and single quotes must be exposed to the shell and then quoted i.e. `'` to `\'`. To reduce the likelyhood of mistakes use grouping and a backreference after the initial string for further instances.

N.B. If the sed invocation is single quoted, the command must first be closed by a single quote, then quoted in the shell and the rest of the command enclosed within single quotes i.e.`sed 's/...'\''.../.../' file`

Comment: Although, exactly this -- using `'` inside single quotes -- is already covered in my answer ;)

Comment: @PesaThe sorry I guess I had started to answer whilst you were amending your answer. I have ameliorated my answer so as to add value.

Comment: No worries at all! :) I just wanted to avoid redundant answers. I like your new approach.